# Replace dashes with spaces just in anchor text

Tags: regex, vim, sed

I just want to replace the dashes with spaces in an anchor HTML code like this:

```
<a href="https://example.com/hello-world-hi">hello-world-hi</a>
```

After substitution it would be:

```
<a href="https://example.com/hello-world-hi">hello world hi</a>
```

How to tell the regular expression to just replace the dashes in the anchor text?

Comment: with perl, `:% perldo s/^<a[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|-/ /g` not sure how robust it is for html tags...

Answer (score 1):

1. Visually select the content of that tag:

   ```
   vit
   ```
2. Perform a substitution on the text covered by the visual selection:

   ```
   :s/\%V-\%V/ /g
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can still do it with substitution:

```
:%s:\(<a [^>]*>\)\(.\{-}\)\(</a>\):\=join([submatch(1),substitute(submatch(2),'-',' ','g'),submatch(3)],''):g
```

Comment: There is nothing practical about this :P

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to parse HTML with regular expressions, but use a parser for it.

For command line processing, there are the [HTML-XML-utils](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/) (packaged for many Linux distros) with their `hxpipe` and `hxunpipe` commands, which turn HTML into a format easily processed by line-based tools and back:

```
$ echo '<a href="https://example.com/hello-world-hi">hello-world-hi</a>' | hxpipe
Ahref CDATA https://example.com/hello-world-hi
(a
-hello-world-hi
)a
-\n
```

Now, we can modify this, for example with GNU sed (`>` is the secondary prompt):

```
$ echo '<a href="https://example.com/hello-world-hi">hello-world-hi</a>' |
> hxpipe |
> sed '/^(a$/,/^)a$)/{/^-/s/-/ /2g}'
Ahref CDATA https://example.com/hello-world hi
(a
-hello world hi
)a
-\n
```

The sed command, a bit better readable and commented:

```
sed '
    /^(a$/,/^)a$)/{   # If we are within an anchor tag...
        /^-/s/-/ /2g  # If the line starts with "-" (text), replace all but the
    }                 #   first hyphen with a space
'
```

`hxpipe` indicates text by starting lines with a `-`, so we replace all hyphens *except* that one. The behaviour for `s///2g` is GNU sed specific and might work differently for other seds.

Finally, we "unpipe" this back to HTML:

```
$ echo '<a href="https://example.com/hello-world-hi">hello-world-hi</a>' |
> hxpipe |
> sed '/^(a$/,/^)a$)/{/^-/s/-/ /2g}' |
> hxunpipe
<a href="https://example.com/hello-world hi">hello world hi</a>
```

Comment: Hmmm. I basically agree that an HTML parser should be used (and I didn't voted). But this hxpipe thingy looks very hackish, especially when combined with sed. A little Python (or whatever) program would be cleaner imo.

Comment: Thank you for introducing this util for HTML parsing. Swiss knife combined with sed.

Comment: @hek2mgl I guess sed just _always_ looks hacky ;) But I just realized I can clean it up a little (no loop required). And yes, Python/Perl or similar would be cleaner, but if you really want something that's pipeable, I found `hxpipe` and `hxunpipe` quite workable for quick prototypes and one-off scripts.

Comment: Well, probably I should give it a try one day. Never heard about html-xml-utils before. Thanks for that.